# Geometry problem!

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the equilateral triangle ABC we send a light beam through The vertex A so that it hits D on side BC so that: BD/BC=1/5. How many times does the light beam have to reflect so that it goes back through vertex A? 
So the answer for this is 7. And here’s how:[image]
Now the question is what happens if instead of BD/BC=1/5 we have BD/BC=3/7?

Comment: This has a hidden part -- show that the vertex you hit is actually $A$ rather than $B$ or $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't get into vertex A, it will get to vertex B. Do your problem has a rule how beams reflect from angles? Does it count as one reflection or two?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much now I have another question maybe you could help with? The question is that if BD/BC=irrational number then the light will never get into a vertex. But if BD/BC=rational number then the light will always get into a vertex. I want to know why this is

Comment: It's quite simple if you know the vectors. Let's say that vector $\vec u=\vec{AB}$, and $\vec v=\vec{BC}$ and origin is in $A$, then every triangle vertex after several reflections over the sides have coordinate $n\vec u+m\vec v$, where $n,m\in\mathbb Z$. Point $D$ has coordinate $\vec u+\frac37\vec v$. If you go along vector $AD$ 7 times its length, you get to the point $7(\vec u+\frac37\vec v)=7\vec u+3\vec v$, which is the vertex. Can you see now how to answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: instead of reflecting the beam off the side of the triangle, reflect the triangle across the edge hit and let the beam pass through the edge. You’ll get a ray in a triangular grid. Think about how and why this works!

Comment: I tired that actually but I still have no idea where to go from there mind giving more help?

Comment: If you tried that, why didn’t you say so in the question? That is the point of saying what you’ve tried. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I’m sorry I didn’t think it was right so I just forgot about it. But I don’t know where it reflects after that move

Comment: It doesn’t reflect, it just keeps going straight. Are you sure you don’t want to try again and detail your working/thoughts because I don’t quite follow “where it reflects after that move” m

Comment: Okay so what I’m trying to say is after the third reflect the light beam can’t reflect onto BC it will go beyond that so wouldn’t it hit AC?

Comment: We’re not reflecting the beam, the beam goes straight. We’re only reflecting the triangle.